# How to measure Facebook Install ads / Google Install Ads on our own backend?

Tags: facebook, mobile, appsflyer

When I congifure Facebook Install ads, there is no place to provide a tracking link(you just pick the facebook app from the dropdown), so how can we tell from our own backend which users are from Facebook Install ads? The same question applies to Google install ads.

I know using 3rd party measurement parters like appsflyer could work, but its too expensive and we wanna track everything ourselves.